# Consulta com relacionamento eloquent

Tags: laravel, query, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Estou me batendo aqui com uma consulta simples no Laravel, eu quero fazer uma consulta na tabela cliente e trazer o endereço do cliente junto.

Observação: sempre que tento ele traz o id do endereço e não do cliente

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'street',
        'number',
        'neighborhood',
        'complement',
        'reference',
        'zip_code',
        'phone',
        'cel_phone',
        'city',
        'state',
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
}

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'cpf',
        'rg',
        'address_id',
    ];

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
    }
}
```

Exemplo da SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 'clients' as A 
     INNER JOIN 'addresses' as B on a.address_id = b.id 
        WHERE a.id =" $id;
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo? Se fez assim `Cliente::with('address')->get()`? Ou não tentou nada?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de relação entre `Client` e `Address`? é 1 cliente para muitos endereços? Eu não entendi bem qual relação quer utilizar, primeiro define qual relação que existe entre essas duas tabelas !

Comment: Cada cliente tem somente um endereço, mas há a possibilidade de mais de um cliente morar no mesmo endereço! Estaria certo dessa forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrigindo seu relacionamento primeiro:

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'street',
        'number',
        'neighborhood',
        'complement',
        'reference',
        'zip_code',
        'phone',
        'cel_phone',
        'city',
        'state',
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class, 'address_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'cpf',
        'rg',
        'address_id',
    ];

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'id', 'address_id');
    }
}
```

Depois de corrigir você vai no controller e chama o model clientes.

```
Client::with('address')->get(); //Para pegar todos clientes com seus endereços

Client::with('address')->whereHas('address', function($query) use ($request){
   $query->where('city', $request->city);
})->get(); // Pegar todos clientes com where na tabela address de city você pode usar qualquer campo que desejar dentro da function do whereHas

Client::all() // Pegar todos clientes com todos relacionamento
```

Veja qual te ajuda e seja feliz.